# What would be the best / idiomatic way to resolve multiple boolean expression?

Tags: rust, boolean-expression

I have to perform multiple boolean operation, not really complex but quite long and as I was trying to get the best readable and understandable result, I came up with multiple solutions, and I'm not sure what would be the "correct" (idiomatic?) way to do it.

I'm not sure there's a "right" answer, as it's maybe subjective, which doesn't interest me if X prefer it that way, but I believe there's wrong answer or better answer, regarding maybe optimization or idiomatic way. Or how the feature are supposed to be used, and in which case.

The goal:

```
pub struct Coord {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}

impl Coord {
    pub fn is_connected(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {}
}
```

Calling self value x1 and y1, and coord value x2 and y2, the result of is_connected would be true if:
`x1 == x2 and either y2 == y+1 or y2 == y-1`
or there's the condition on one line are completed

| x2 | y2 | y<6 | y%2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x+1 | y+1 | true | 0 |
| x-1 | y-1 | true | 1 |
| x-1 | y+1 | false | 0 |
| x+1 | y-1 | false | 1 |

The raw, boolean chained solution would look like that:

```
pub fn is_connected2(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {
    coord.x == self.x && (coord.y == self.y+1 || coord.y == self.y-1)
        || (self.y < 6
            && ((self.y % 2 == 0 && coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y+1)
                || (self.y % 2 == 1 && coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y-1)))
        || (self.y > 6
            && ((self.y % 2 == 0 && coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y+1)
                || (self.y % 2 == 1 && coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y-1)))
}
```

I believe it's a bit hard to read.
As rust as this awesome feature, the match, I wanted to use it, especially cause I'm still testing it. But I completely forgot that you can't (as far as I know) put variable value in the arm, and have to add them in the guard, which make the match look way bigger than what I originally wanted (I was thinking of a `match (self, road)` and do stuff like `((x,y),(x+1,y+1))` in the match).

Hence, while I think the match is clearer, I'm not sure if one of the two options is better (because one have everything in the guard and the other in the pattern, and I don't know which one is better/more idiomatic). I'm also putting the rest of the expression in the result, while I could put it in the guard too. But to have this much choice make me believe that some of this choice would be "anti-rust", as using the feature in a way that wasn't intended or non idiomatic.

```
pub fn is_connected(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {
    coord.x == self.x && (coord.y == self.y+1 || coord.y == self.y-1)
        || match self.y {
            _ if self.y < 6 && self.y % 2 == 0 => {coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y+1},
            _ if self.y < 6 && self.y % 2 == 1 => {coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y-1},
            _ if self.y > 6 && self.y % 2 == 0 => {coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y+1},
            _ if self.y > 6 && self.y % 2 == 1 => {coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y-1}, 
            _ => false
        }
}

pub fn is_connected_bis(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {
    coord.x == self.x && (coord.y == self.y+1 || coord.y == self.y-1)
        || match (self.y < 6, self.y%2) {
            (true, 0) => {coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y+1}, 
            (true, 1) => {coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y-1}, 
            (false, 0) => {coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y+1},
            (false, 1) => {coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y-1}, 
            _ => false
        }    
}

pub fn is_connected4(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {
    // bis would be to take the y<6 and y%2 in the guard as well
    match (self.y<6, self.y%2) {
        (_,_) if coord.x == self.x && coord.y == self.y+1 => true,
        (_,_) if coord.x == self.x && coord.y == self.y-1 => true,
        (true, 0) if coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y+1 => true,
        (true, 1) if coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y-1 => true,
        (false, 0) if coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y+1 => true,
        (false, 1) if coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y-1 => true,
        _ => false
    } 
}
```

There's also the good old fashioned if way:

```
pub fn is_connected3(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {
    let res: bool = coord.x == self.x && (coord.y == self.y+1 || coord.y == self.y-1);
    res ||
    // or if res {} else {}... 
        if self.y < 6 {
            if self.y % 2 == 0 {
                coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y+1
            } else {
                coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y-1
            }
        } else {
            if self.y % 2 == 0 {
                coord.x == self.x-1 && coord.y == self.y+1
            } else {
                coord.x == self.x+1 && coord.y == self.y-1
            }
        }
}
```

I have to admit that my question was originally motivated by how to have variable in the condition of the match, before I fully realize what guard was supposed to be. My question evolved then, but still have some trace from the original with all the match expression.

I'm especially curious if some of the match I wrote are "bad", not in a subjective/how to read properly way, but regarding how rust is designed and feature are intended to be used.

Comment: All of the code snippets you included should compile down to the same thing (when compiling with optimizations, of course), so the difference is purely subjective.

Comment: @Aplet123 I see. As I was writing some of them I was wondering if this is even working, proper or just a kinda hack. And after reading some of the answers on other question for other subject, I ended being probably way too careful about the code I write, thinking it's obviously bad or breaking things or such. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cool thing about boolean expressions, is that they're frequently can be simplified. I haven't tested the next code, but I hope it's equivalent to the table you've shown.

```
pub fn is_connected(&self, coord: &Coord) -> bool {
    let is_y_even = (self.y % 2 == 0);
    let adjusted_x = if (self.y < 6) == is_y_even { self.x+1 } else { self.x-1 };
    let adjusted_y = if is_y_even { self.y+1 } else { self.y-1 };
    adjusted_x == coord.x && adjusted_y == coord.y
}
```